# Terraform use data resource to get Cluster Snapshot?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a global Aurora RDS cluster that takes automated snapshot everyday. My DB instance looks like this :-

```
new-test ( Global Database )
   
new-test-db ( Primary Cluster )

new-test-db-0 ( Writer Instance )
```

I have enabled automated snapshots for the db. What i am trying to achieve is to get the `ARN` for my snapshot using `data resource`. My ARN is something like this :-

```
arn:aws:rds:us-west-2:123456789101:cluster-snapshot:rds:new-test-db-2022-08-23-08-06
```

This is what my `data` resource looks like :-

```
data "aws_db_cluster_snapshot" "db" {
  for_each               = toset(var.rds_sources)
  db_cluster_identifier  = each.key
  most_recent            = true
}
```

where `var.rds_sources` is a list of strings. But when i try to access the arn using :-

```
data.aws_db_cluster_snapshot.db[*].db_cluster_snapshot_arn
```

I keep running into

```
 Error: Unsupported attribute
│ 
│   on ../main.tf line 73, in resource "aws_iam_policy" "source_application":
│   73:     cluster_data_sources  = jsonencode(data.aws_db_cluster_snapshot.db[*].db_cluster_snapshot_arn)
│ 
│ This object does not have an attribute named "db_cluster_snapshot_arn".
```

Which is weird since the attribute is laid out in the official [docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/db_cluster_snapshot). Thank you for the help.

This is my provider file :-

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 3.75"
    }
    archive = "~> 2.2.0"
  }
  required_version = "~> 1.2.6"
}
```

Comment: Are you using the latest provider version?

Comment: Please add that to the question, not comments section.

Comment: @MarkoE Done. Please see the updates.

Comment: It seems it was there in the older provider versions as well. Can you try `jsonencode(values(data.aws_db_cluster_snapshot.db)[*].db_cluster_snapshot_arn)`?

Comment: @MarkoE That worked like a charm. Can you please add that as an answer and i'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the data source is using `for_each`, the result will be a map of key value pairs. In terraform, there is a built-in function `values` [1] which can be used to fetch the values of a map. The return value is a list, so in order to get all the values for all the keys the splat operator is used [2]. Then, since the data source is returning multiple attributes and only one is required (namely `db_cluster_snapshot_arn`), the final expression needed is as follows:

```
jsonencode(values(data.aws_db_cluster_snapshot.db)[*].db_cluster_snapshot_arn)
```

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/values

[2] https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/splat